# RadioGroup enables to check all answers

Tags: android, radio-group

I've made an `RadioGroup` and I'm adding `RadioButtons` to it all programmatically.
The problem is, when running I can check all options and cannot uncheck them.
Here is my code:

```
        optionsContainer = new RadioGroup(_myActivity);
        this.setId(IdDispencer.DispenceID());

        for (int i=0; i < options.size(); i++){

            RadioButton asw = new RadioButton(_myActivity);
            asw.setText(options.get(i));
            asw.setId(IdDispencer.DispenceID());
            optionsContainer.addView(asw);
        }
```

P.S. 1 - I've tried to setup an array to hold the radio buttons as showed here:
[Android RadioGroup checks more than one RadioButton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8265034/android-radiogroup-checks-more-than-one-radiobutton)
But with no success.

P.S. 2 - This is very weird, the behavior is inconsistent. Sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't.
On my emulator running 2.3.3 it show this behavior but on my SGS1 with CM9 it shows the problematic behavior all the time.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and the solution I found is to set an id to each radio button (I didn't do it at all).

In your code, it seems that you give at each button the same id. Maybe the problem is here.