# Android RadioButton allow more than one to be check

Tags: android, radio-button, android-button

I have a **radiogroup with about 30 radiobuttons**. I have looked around on stackoverflow and found a few posts about the accidental allowing of multiple radiobuttons to be checked. They were **not in a radiogroup, or had problems with their id**.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8265034/android-radiogroup-checks-more-than-one-radiobuttonhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/17157705/radiogroup-allows-multiple-radiobuttons-to-be-selected

How can I purposefully allow **3 radiobutton to be selected** at a time
and **implement a listener for those three** selected.

I suspect I am doing something wrong. Is there another UI element out there that can help me get what I am looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RadioGroups are designed to only allow 1 selection. It's confusing for users to have what is basically checkbox-like behaviour when they are using a RadioGroup.

If you really need to do this, you either need to use multiple RadioGroup objects, or use checkboxes instead.

Android Checkbox documentation is here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox.html

You can attach listeners to the checkbox objects by using the following:

```
public void setOnCheckedChangeListener (CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener listener)
```

Comment: ok, but now how would I make all 30 of my checkboxes only have three ones available to check at a time?

Comment: I would have a variable accessible to the activity/fragment that the checkboxes live in, say, `mCount` and then `mCount += 1` or vice-versa when a checkbox is ticked/unticked. Then when handling a check event in `public abstract void onCheckedChanged (CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)` you check `if mCount == 3` and handle accordingly. An alternative would be to loop through your checkboxes and `setEnabled(false)` if there are already 3 ticked. I'm not sure which is the least costly approach in terms of writing code and the actual execution.